# download counter increases by thrice when using a download manager like IDM

Tags: php, wordpress, download, counter

I have created a simple php download counter, which upon clicking the download link, captures and saves details like ip, file-name, no of times the download has been made, etc. Everything works fine so far. Counter also gets incremented for each download made, but the problem pops up when one uses IDM (or similar download managers); **then the counter gets incremented by thrice for each download!**

The code I'm using looks like this (on WordPress environment) -

```
global $wpdb;

            $db_table_name = $wpdb->prefix. 'test_downloads_info';              
            $sql = "SELECT download_count FROM $db_table_name WHERE download_name = %s";
            $result = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare($sql, $download_name), ARRAY_A);

            // If the row fetched has values..
            if(!empty($result) && !empty($result['download_count'])){

                // Increment the counter by one..
                $download_count = $result['download_count'] + 1;
                // And update the corresponding row..
                $update_result = $wpdb->update($db_table_name, array('download_ip'=> $download_ip, 'download_count'=> $download_count, 'download_date'=> $download_date), array('download_name'=> $download_name));

            }

            // Otherwise..
            else{

                // Insert the new records..
                $insert_result = $wpdb->insert($db_table_name, array('download_name'=> $download_name, 'download_url'=> $download, 'download_ip'=> $download_ip, 'download_count'=> $download_count, 'download_date'=> $download_date), array('%s', '%s', '%s', '%d', '%s'));

            }               

            /**
            * Prepare to force download the requested file
            */

            // Required for IE..
            if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
                ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

            // Send all the needed headers for download prompting.. 
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate; post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Cache-Control: private', false);
            header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"". basename($download). "\"");
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            /*header('Content-Length: '. filesize($download));*/
            header('Connection: close');
            readfile($download);
            exit();         

        }
```

So the main problem is that the  counter gets incremented by twice or thrice if one uses a download manager like IDM. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Also, I'm a php newbie.

Comment: What I think is going on is that, download manager sites use multiple connections to different servers to download the same file in order to increase the speed, and in turn increasing your counter for each server used. I've Google'd your problem and the only thing I found which may be of help, can be found on this page **http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10294626-Disable-download-manager** - You can further your search with the keywords I used being `"how to prevent download managers from downloading php"` or others you may see fit.

Answer (score 0):

IDM work by requesting different part of the same file to parallelize download.

You should try to check if the `$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']` variable is present, and do not increment your counter if it is. This variable is used by IDM-like software, or by browser to resume a download.